# Правильно ли я нашла ключ с максимальным значением словаря в классе?

Tags: python, классы, dict

Всем привет я только начала знакомиться с классами и решила попытаться сделать свое первое упражнение, оно работает, но я не знаю правильный ли код.

Текст упражнения

> С использованием класса M_set решить задачи:
>
> a) найти символ, входящий в строку S максимальное количество раз;
>
> b) проверить, состоят ли строки S1, S2 из одних и тех же символов,
> которые входят в эти строки одинаковое количество раз;
>
> c) проверить, верно ли, что все символы строки S1, входят также в
> строку S2, причем не меньшее количество раз, чем у S1

Я пока сделала только а

```
class M_set(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

```
a = M_set()
S = 'I love my mommm'
for a.b in S:
    a[a.b] = a.get(a.b,0)+1
#здесь я получила вот это, но я не понимаю почему 1 элемент словаря такой поэтому я решила его 
#просто удалить
del a['b']#{'b': 'm', 'I': 1, ' ': 3, 'l': 1, 'o': 2, 'v': 1, 'e': 1, 'm': 5, 'y': 1}
print(a)
print(max(a, key=a.get))
```

Кто видит что здесь есть какая-то ошибка, или что здесь что-то можно лучше и легче написать, напишите пожалуйста свои комментарии или коды к этому, буду очень благодарна

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу текст упражнения

Comment: @gil9red, поддерживаю. Иначе не понятно нафига здесь класс

Comment: Не знаю почему у вас там `b` затесалось, но если не делать тот трюк с словарем, а взять обычный, то код нормально отработает: `a = dict()` + `S = 'I love my mommm'` + `for c in S: a[c] = a.get(c,0)+1`

Comment: Что за "строки S1 и S2"?

Comment: А `M_set` ранее был описан в упражнения? Или мб было описано какими свойствами/возможностями он обладает? Просто непонятно зачем он вам нужен и именно в таком виде :)

Comment: @gil9red Увы но нет, насколько я поняла здесь не целесообразно использовать класс или нужно сделать полностью все подпункты и потом что-то будет понятно?

Comment: @st040506, честно, нехватает примеров для б) и в) да и с таким охото разбираться с свежей головой :) Если с б) и в) не сможете справиться, то лучше задайте отдельный вопрос по ним, добавив вашу попытку решить :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключ `'b'` равный `m` у вас появился из-за `a.b` в цикле. До цикла у вас словарь `a` пустой, а при первой итерации у него появится значение `'b' = 'I'`, т.к. при итерации `for a.b in S:` в `a.b` будут присваиваться значения:

```
a.b = S[0]
a.b = S[1]
...
a.b = S[n-1]
```

Если не использовать `a.b`, то это не создаст тот ключ:

```
class M_set(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

a = M_set()
S = 'I love my mommm'
for c in S:
    a[c] = a.get(c, 0)+1

print(a)
print(max(a, key=a.get))
# {'I': 1, ' ': 3, 'l': 1, 'o': 2, 'v': 1, 'e': 1, 'm': 5, 'y': 1}
# m
```

Кст, если же `a.b` необходимо, то это можно обойти, если у `M_set` убрать `self.__dict__ = self`, тогда присваивание в `a.b` не будет создавать ключ `b`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь и за время, которое потратили на это:)

Comment: @st040506, пожалуйста :)